# Updating a column of a snowflake table using stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am creating a stored procedure in snowflake. I want to update ORG_ID column OF EMPLOYEE table with value 'ZZ'. Here is my code, not sre where am I going wrong.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE NEW(VAL VARCHAR)
    RETURNS string
    LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
    AS
    $$      
                          
        let sql_command = `update EMPLOYEE set ORG_ID = ${VAL}`;
        snowflake.execute({sqlText: sql_command});

    return 'success';
    $$;
    
call NEW('ZZ');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables should be bound:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE NEW(VAL VARCHAR)
    RETURNS string
    LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
    AS
    $$      
                          
        let sql_command = `update EMPLOYEE set ORG_ID = :1`;
        snowflake.execute({sqlText: sql_command, binds: [VAL]});

    return 'success';
    $$;
```

Related: [Binding Variables](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-javascript.html#label-stored-procedures-binding-variables)

---

String interpolation could also be used but it is prone to SQL Injection :

```
let sql_command = `update EMPLOYEE set ORG_ID = '${VAL}'`;
```